# Change field value on checkbox click

Tags: php, atk4

I have a simple form like this:

```
$label=$p->add('View_HtmlElement')->setElement('h4')->set('Test');

$f=$p->add('Form'); 

$f->addField('Checkbox','click')->js('click')->getElement($label)->set('HELLO WORLD')->execute();

$f->addSubmit('Accept');
```

I couldn't find the way to make this, I need to change the `$label` value from 'Test' to 'HELLO WORLD'.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like so:

```
$label=$this->add('View_HtmlElement')->setElement('h4')->set('Test');
$f=$this->add('Form');
$f->addField('Checkbox','click')->js('click',$label->js()->text('hallo world'));
```

OR
If you want to use Accept Button do it that way

```
$label=$this->add('View_HtmlElement')->setElement('h4')->set('Test');

$f=$this->add('Form');
$f->addField('Checkbox','click');
$f->addSubmit('Accept');
if($f->isSubmitted()){
    if($f->get('click')){
        $this->js(null,$label->js()->text('hallo world'))->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to learn jQuery first ;)

```
$label=$this->add('View')->setElement('h4')->set('Test');
$f=$this->add('Form');
$f->addField('Checkbox','click')->js('click',$label->js()->html('HELLO WORLD'));
$f->addSubmit('Accept');
```

Comment: it's `text()` not `html()`, he only wants to change the label.